# Selected items (using checkbox) should be on Top of recyclerview

Tags: android, sorting, filtering, android-recyclerview

I am using search on the recycler view having a checkbox and text view on the cell. 
Now when i search something and checked some items then these selected items should be on top of the list .

How can we do this ? [this is the kind of list m using. I want these selected items should be on top of list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhCgH.jpg)

Comment: Sort your search items based on checkbox status.

Comment: If you are using a list (ArraytList), when checkbox is checked remove the item from current list and insert it at position zero of the list and notify the adapter.